# Racket: How to combine two lists pairwise with f

Tags: list, racket, fold

I implemented a function (combine f n l1 l2) that combines two lists pairwise with f and returns a list:

```
(check-expect (combine string-append "" '("1" "2" "3") '("4" "5" "6")) '("14" "25" "36"))
(check-expect (combine + 0 '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6)) '(5 7 9))


(define (combine f n l1 l2)
    (if (empty? l1) '()
      (cons (foldr f n (first (zip l1 l2)))
        (combine f n (rest l1) (rest l2)))))
```

It uses the (zip l1 l2) function I implemented previously:

```
(check-expect (zip '(1 2 3 0) '(4 5 6))'((1 4) (2 5) (3 6)))

(define (zip l1 l2)
  (local
    [(define (take lst n)
         (if (zero? n)
             '()
             (cons (first lst)
                   (take (rest lst)(- n 1)))))
     (define min-lsts
       (min (length l1) (length l2)))]
    (foldr (lambda (e1 e2 acc) (cons (list e1 e2) acc)) '() (take l1 min-lsts) (take l2 min-lsts))))
```

(combine f n l1 l2) works as expected, but is there a way to change it to (combine f l1 l2) that does not expect n but still uses foldr?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you always have two arguments you can replace the recursion with `foldr` and just use the two arguments directly:

```scm
(define (combine f l1 l2)
  (foldr (lambda (a1 a2 acc)
           (cons (f a1 a2)
                 acc))
         '()
         l1
         l2))
```

Also zip is implemented overly complicated. It can be done far simpler:

```scm
(define (zip l1 l2)
  (map list l1 l2))
```